# Numeral Citation Scripts

Tags: style, technical-writing, formatting, citations

I am writing a report in Farsi and using `ieeetr` bibliography style for my references. This style uses numeral references like [1] [2] etc but regarding context (Farsi) I am using Arabic number scripts like [۱], [۲] etc, but in the bibliography section, I am using a Latin script, again due to context (English references).  Am I obliged to use Latin scripts for numbers in the text where I am citing an English article instead of [۱], [۲] etc?
What about Farsi articles? What about Chinese?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of citing is, that the reader can refer to the sources you used for your text.

Imagine your user is a Chinese. He does not know English and hardly care about the numbers. Now he looks up your citation source, sees it is in English and can ask someone for a translation of that source if he really needs one.

The point here is "looks up your citation source". Is *the reader* able (or is it easier for him) to look up the citation source if the number is in Chinese? Obviously, so use what your reader understands.